# MS CRM 2013 Mail Merge cannot be checked

Tags: email, merge, dynamics-crm-2013

In Microsoft CRM 2013, when you create an entity you can either check this box "Mail Merge", or you can leave it unchecked. This item should be available for check / uncheck after that as well if it doesn't have the † sign after it.

Question: Why can I check this box, and how can I check it?

Any answers will be appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwURX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, CRM doesn't allow you to check/uncheck this box due to the fact the the *Invoice* entity is a system one. Why Microsoft made this decision is another question.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. Actually I found this workaround -> You create a custom entity, in my case Invoice Tab, and you create a 1 to N relation between the old and the new entity, and then N:1 relation from the old to the new Entity. I have it here in my post in the CRM Community. 

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/143252.aspx